Transit Dubai with Duty Free
I will have family travelling to my wedding in Bali from Ireland in September 2024. I would like them to bring some Irish whiskey from Dublin duty free. Being a wedding I would be investing a good amount into the bottles. They would be bought in Dublin and placed into security sealed bags or STEBs.
I have heard lots of stories of people having their liquids refused onto their second flight if not purchased at duty free Dubai. When purchased in Dubai the shop staff brings the product to your boarding gate and you collect as you get on the plane. Singapore airlines even discourages the purchase of duty free outside of Dubai.
Does anyone have personal recent experience of transiting Dubai with Duty free from another country and can advise on the do’s and don’ts.
I have done lots of research on LAGs and STEBs and know that Indonesia will accept STEBs. I may be biased as I know I can't transit with STEBs on Australia bound flights due to Australian rules. Also Dubai duty free isn't an option as their Irish whiskey selection isn't great.

Have you compared duty free prices with normal shop prices in Ireland? If bought before the start of the journey the alcohol can be packed into the hold and there is no risk of not allowed onto the next flight.

Remember that there is a duty-free allowance of 1l per passenger in Indonesia, and that any excess is not taxed but destroyed.

I believe the issue you refer to is related to Australian rules (where they do not recognise STEBs and only accept liquids over the usual 100ml limit if delivered by the DF shop at the gate), and applies regardless of the transit airport (as well as direct flights from places where they don’t do gate delivery service). It doesn’t look like DXB themselves have any issue with it, though I have no experience with this myself.

However, remember that if they exit the transit area for any reason (self-transfer so need to re-check bags, or staying overnight in Dubai, even through the stopover program), they will most definitely not be allowed back into the secure area with those bottles, even in STEBs.

Hi jcaron, thanks for your helpful replies. I agree with all your comments. They have a 2hr layover so they won't be exiting the transit zone, their checked bags will go straight through as it's Emirates to Emirates. I have transited from Australia to Ireland via Qatar and Abu Dhabi just never Dubai with STEBs no problem. Each passenger will carry 700ml. The information is vague DXB with many bad experiences. On here duty free issues are mainly with DXB - although all the posts I've seen the OP has been in error (i.e. leaving transit area or no STEB).

Having just done this a month ago, we weren't allowed to take any liquids of any amount - even water - through to the transit area with us (on our persons or in our bags), and had to empty bottles out before going through. This includes anything we purchased from duty free, though again, this was on our person and not brought through by duty free staff. Whether this is what is supposed to happen or not I'm unsure, but it is definitely what was enforced.

@user25730 can I ask where you were travelling from and to? Also if your duty free was in security plastic bags packed by the duty free staff? this is the closest potential answer I have received.

@HughKelly I was travelling from Manchester, UK, to Melbourne, Australia. My duty free was not in security plastic bags (we simply had bought bottles of water for some of my family from duty free, and I was taking my own refillable bottle). We were told that we had to empty them into a nearby bin, then refill them on the other side.

The liquids are refused because of security, not import or export. It is not allowed to bring liquids larger than the maximum size into a flight cabin, with the sole exception of when they were purchased in the duty free of the airport you are departing from. This is true at most airports, not just Dubai.
Because it is a security thing and not a customs thing you can get round the problem by carrying the liquid in checked baggage. Larger liquid containers are permitted in checked baggage. You would have to purchase it outside of Dublin duty free. You should make sure the total alcohol you are carrying is under the import limit for your final destination. They won't care about the difference between alcohol bought in duty free and elsewhere.
Checked baggage does have other issues. It's possible your whiskey may be stolen (though alcohol isn't a prime target for thieves, they prefer jewellery and electronics). It's possible it may be damaged, though I've transported wine in checked baggage many times and never had a breakage (or a theft). You should pack it with plenty of protection.

This is not quite correct. In most cases, duty free items bought at one airport for travel involving a connection will be sold in a special sealed bag (a Security Tamper Evident Bag (STEB)), with the receipt visible inside the bag, which gives an exemption for the usual liquid rules at connection airports for those items (deemed safe). There are exceptions (like for flights to/from Australia) where this doesn’t work, but in most cases it does.
